# SQL recursive. Coin change problem. - Trying to figure out how to solve coin change problem using recursion

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

I'm trying to find out how many coins it takes to give out change and one of the conditions is to give out large coins first. i.e. 10 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1. I know this task can be solved by using loop, but i wanna understand how to solve it with recursive

There is a table:

```
coin
| id   |  coin  | 
| ---- | ------ |
|  1   |    1   |
|  2   |    2   |
|  3   |    5   |
|  4   |   10   |
```

i.e change = 43

```
43 - 10 = 33   ->   33 - 10 = 23   ->   23 - 10 = 13   ->   13 - 10 = 3   ->   3 can't be decrease by 10 
3 -  can't be decrease by 5 
3 - 2 = 1   ->   1 - can't be decrease by 2
1 - 1 = 0   ->   end
```

[One of example how i try solve this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf9g6.png)

Trying to get:

output :

```
| id   | count  |  -- how many times coin was used/iterration count 
| ---- | ------ |
|  4   |    4   |
|  3   |    0   |  
|  2   |    1   |
|  1   |    1   |
```

Comment: Please don't link to images/documents - add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use a recursive CTE to subtract the higher denomination coin in each iteration until the remaining money reaches zero.

For example, you can do:

```
with recursive
p (amount) as (select 43), -- parameter "amount" here
coins (denom) as (select 10 union select 5 union select 2 union select 1),
h (denom, remainder) as ( (
  select c.denom, p.amount - c.denom
  from p
  join coins c on p.amount >= c.denom
  order by c.denom desc limit 1
 ) union all (
  select c.denom, h.remainder - c.denom
  from h
  join coins c on h.remainder >= c.denom
  order by c.denom desc limit 1
  )
)
select * from h;
```

Result:

```
 denom  remainder 
 ------ --------- 
 10     33        
 10     23        
 10     13        
 10     3         
 2      1         
 1      0
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TVONRzQt).